# .htaccess redirect https://olddomain to https://newdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've looked all over stackoverflow for this particular question but haven't found it, so I'm going to ask. We have have two domains. I did a 301 redirect in .htaccess and it works like a charm:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newdomain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The idea is to redirect all traffic - http and https to https newdomain.com. So far it redirects http requests to https newdomain.com, but does not redirect https olddomain.com to https newdomain.com.

Do you have any idea how I can make https olddomain.com do a 301 redirect to https newdomain.com using .htaccess?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happends when you access https olddomain? And do you have a valid cert on olddomain.com?

Comment: Yes, I do have a valid third-party cert. It just does not redirect me. It shows https olddomain.com instead of redirecting me to https newdomain.com

Comment: Does olddomain.com and newdomain.com both go to the same place?

Comment: Yes, they do go to the same server.

Comment: Really the rewriterule by itself should actually be enough to redirect all requests to new domain. Have you used `ModRewrite` with `https` on the olddomain before?

Comment: No, I haven't. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, it seems the redirect works internally, but not when the request comes from the Threat Management Gateway (Microsoft Fiewall).

Comment: It was not the TMG, my browser has cached the redirect somehow. When I cleared the cookies https olddomain.com is still not redirected to https newdomain.com. I'm pulling my hair out now. Http to https redirection works, but https to https does not.